# pausing a loop in AIX to wait for user input

Tags: scripting, ksh, aix, user-input

I'm searching for a scripting mechanism that can realize the following idea.
Loop over a list and stop/wait on "read x" until the next input from a user.
I know the following script is not working! As far as I know, the loop has to be done via another input channel, but I don't know how to do this. My script is:

```
while read a
 do
    echo ------- $a  -----------
    echo ------- check $a  ----- go on with return --------
    read x
done < list
```

Comment: I updated your post a bit; if it's not actually limited to AIX, feel free to clarify ([edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/282711/edit))

Answer (score 0):

Is `more -d -1 list` good enough?

Maybe in a script like:

```
#! /bin/sh

echo 'Check each line.  Hit spacebar or enter to continue after each line.'
echo
more -d -1 list
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. "more -d -1" shows a full side of the "list (file)"  I wanted to see line by line and confirm each line with a return, space or something else.   regards, Gerold

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "shows a full side of the "list (file)"?    paging the file one line at a time and prompting the user to hit space after each line is **exactly** what `more -d -1` does.  except maybe it doesn't for you, i just noticed the /aix tag.  `more` from `util-linux` does what i said.  check `man more` on your system to see if those options (or similar) are available on aix.

Answer (score 0):

I found the preferred solution, using another channel....

```
#! /bin/ksh

while read a <&3
do
  echo ------  $a ----------
  echo weiter mit return
  read a
done 3< abc
```